# How to "Include" in a JSON API Post in PHP?

Tags: php, json-api, php-curl

I am working with the [Planning Center API](https://developer.planning.center/docs/#/introduction), it was built to conform to the JSON API 1.0 specification.

We are needing to post a persons data to Planning center. The API seems to break up a person, from their phone number and email. I am new to working with the this so I am not sure if you can post them all in the same cURL request, or if I would need 3 requests. My understanding (possibly misguided) is that I can "include" the email and phone number in the POST request.

This is what I have:

```
$person = '{
          "data": {
            "type": "Person",
            "attributes": {
              "first_name": "Test",
              "last_name": "User"
            },
            "relationships": {
              "primary_campus": {
                "data": { "type": "PrimaryCampus", "id": "123" }
              }
            }
          },
          "include":{
          "data": {
            "type": "emails",
            "attributes": {"address": "test@test.com"}
            }
          }
        }';

$channel = curl_init();
curl_setopt( $channel, CURLOPT_URL, "https://api.planningcenteronline.com/people/v2/people" );
//curl_setopt( $channel, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt( $channel, CURLOPT_USERPWD, $application_ID.":".$application_secret );
curl_setopt( $channel, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt( $channel, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $person);
curl_exec($channel);
echo $channel;
```

This only seems to create the persons First name and last name (and associated campus). The email is not created.

Here is the [documentation for the email.](https://developer.planning.center/docs/#/apps/people/2018-08-01/vertices/email)
Here is the [documentation for the person](https://developer.planning.center/docs/#/apps/people/2018-08-01/vertices/person).

Any ideas what I am missing here?

Comment: it's not massively clear from the documentation but https://developer.planning.center/docs/#/introduction/json-api implies that the "include" idea is something to be used when fetching data from the API, not sending things to it. Perhaps you should ask the maintainers for clarification. Also if a person can be associated with many emails, then if the "include" thing does work for sending, then I'd guess it would expect a list (i.e. array) not just a single object. But then again that ought to result in a validation error if you supply the wrong format.

Comment: Have you tried passing the items as an array under the `data` element?

Comment: I just tried passing the email address as an array and received an error for invalid JSON. I did also try to pass it under the data block, but also got an invalid json error. From your comments, it seems perhaps I was not far off, but the documentation is a bit to vague. I suppose I should reach out to them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JSON API Specification v1.0 does not support bulk creation. If this specific API does not implement additional functionality that's not part of JSON API specification, you can't create a person with it's associated email in only one request.

*Side note: This will likely be supported by upcoming v1.1 version trough a feature called Operations. You can find more details in [this pending pull request](https://github.com/json-api/json-api/pull/1254).*

So to put it short: As far as I got their specific implementation you have to create a person with first request and then create an email address associated to it with another request.